# How do I merge 2 lists and update one list with the property of another

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I am working with an API that has separate calls for `Order` and `OrderItems`.

I have an object called `Order` with a property called `OrderItems`.

```
    [JsonConverter(typeof(SingleOrArrayConverter<OrderItem>))]
    public List<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
```

After the first call to the `Order` endpoint, the `OrderItems` property is empty because I haven't made a call to the `OrderItems` endpoint.

After the call, I have 2 lists:

```
        //get the orders
        var ordersBody = this._apiClient.Get("Orders", filters);
        var ordersAsList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(ordersBody);
        var orders = ordersAsList.SuccessResponse.Body.Orders.Order;

        var orderFilterList = new List<AbstractFilter>() { new OrdersFilter(orders) };

        //grab the order items
        var orderItemsBody = this._apiClient.Get("MultipleOrderItems", orderFilterList);
        var orderItemsAsList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(orderItemsBody);
        var items = orderItemsAsList.SuccessResponse.Body.Orders.Order;
```

How do I loop over the results merging the two collections together so that the OrderItems from one list is matched with the other?

Comment: Does the `OrderItem` class have an `OrderId` or some other property to use for joining?

Comment: Yes, they are both instances of Order and both have an OrderId property. Just one is filled with values except the OrderItems property and the other has null values for all except the OrderItems property